# Minimal projective space containing projective variety independent of base field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In this question I ask whether ambient spaces descend to models of varieties.

Let $k\subset K$ be a non-trivial extension of algebraically closed fields, e.g., $\overline{\mathbb Q}\subset \mathbb C$.

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $K$ which can be defined over $k$ (as an abstract scheme).

Assume that $X$ can be embedded in $\mathbb P^n_K$, i.e., there is a closed immersion from $X$ into $\mathbb P^n_K$. Is there a model $X_0$ of $X$ over $k$ such that $X_0$ can be embedded in $\mathbb P^n_k$?

What if $k$ is of characteristic zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X=Y\times_k K$ for some variety $Y$ over $k$. The closed immersion $i: Y\times_k K\to\mathbb P^n_K$ is defined by using finitely many coefficients in $K$, so it is defined over a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$: 
$$i_S: Y\times_k S\to \mathbb P^n_S=\mathbb P^n_k \times_k S $$
where $S$ is the affine variety associated to $A$, and $i_S$ is an $S$-morphism. 
Take a closed point $s\in S$ and you will have a closed immersion 
$$ Y=Y\times \{ s \} \to \mathbb P^n_k \times \{ s\}=\mathbb P^n_k.$$

Comment: This works indeed and answers my question. (I don't think the base-change to $K$ of Y embedded in $\mathbb P^n_k$ will be X with its chosen embedding in $\mathbb P^n_k$ because we're "specializing". Nevertheless, it answers the question.)

Comment: @Andrew: of course not, otherwise the initial embedding would be a "constant" one and there is no reason for that.